# Facebook Share Link - Share To A Page On Mobile

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if anyone has a solution to a small but major problem for me. I have coded a share button for Facebook using sharer.php, however, if the button is pressed on a mobile device Facebook isn't giving the user the option to share to a page or a group, it only will post to their personal profile. Unlike on desktop/laptop you get a drop down which gives the option, like in the attached images.

So a) is there a way around this b) is there a way to set Share To A Page as default?

You can see on the first image on my iPhone there is no option to change where it's shared....

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1873285809556648/

Answer (score 0):

to share a an url, website, in facebook u can use:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URLHERE
```

so, to get the thumbnail, title and the excerpt, to show properly in anywhere, u need to set in ur website as meta-tags inside head tags. like:

```
<!-- FB Share -->
<meta property="og:url" content="URLHERE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE HERE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC HERE" />
<meta property="og:image" content="URLIMAGE" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600" />
<!-- FB Share -->
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but that's not answering my question, the meta tags and the share url is fine. The problem is not the fact that it's not working and picking up the post, the problems is on a mobile phone the share doesn't give the user the option to save to a page or group like desktop does.

Comment: maybe another way to get posts to share is to press the "insert" button in the post or page and copy the iframe src url, is like: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=URLENCODED for example https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgolfistas.dechile%2Fposts%2F1182254711871506%3A0